# How to assign the type of a variable based on a conditional statement that checks if a pointer is a nullptr or not?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

```
struct Legacy {
  double cost;
  double price;
  double impact;
  double permanent;
};

struct Latest {
  // declaration omitted
  double cost;
  double price;
  double impact;
};


// I'm using "M" here to denote some custom type
template <typename T> 
void compute_rest_of_variables(T& obj, std::unique_ptr<M> ptr) {
  if (ptr == nullptr) {
    obj.permanent = function_that_computes_permanent();
    obj.impact = function_that_computes_legacy_impact();
  } else {
    obj.impact = function_that_computes_latest_impact();
  }
}

int main () {
  // ptr is determined at runtime
  auto obj = (ptr == nullptr) ? Legacy{} : Latest{};
  // computed the shared attributes of Legacy and Latest
  obj.cost = function_that_computes_cost();
  obj.price = function_that_computes_price();
  compute_rest_of_variables();
}
```

Compiling this gives the error

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:31: error: operands to ?: have different types ‘Legacy’ and ‘Latest’
```

Is there a way to achieve the same or similar behavior?

Comment: You can't, all types have to be determined at compile-time

Comment: @UnholySheep Is there an alternative approach to accomplish what I want (or something similar)?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you are doing, which will require more context

Comment: For that you need us to tell us what you want to achieve. Compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @UnholySheep Just updated the OP with additional context

Comment: Can you change `Legacy` and `Latest`? You could factor the common parts into a base class, and use a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` + virtual methods for the parts that are specific to each type. If not, then you could use a `std::variant` with the visitor pattern.

Comment: @RaymondChen I was thinking of doing that but in this case, `Legacy` would effectively become the base case, but the the concept of `Legacy` and `Latest` are conceptually different and it just so happens they share some common variables, so it doesn't make a whole lot of sense conceptually to think of `Latest` as a subclass of `Legacy`

Comment: @RaymondChen I might just go with the union approach as a quick solution since we might deprecate this piece of code in the near future. Never really used unions before however but it seems straightforward

Comment: Don't use a `union` if you have C++17.  `std::variant` is much nicer (and much safer)

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve something like that with `std::variant` (C++17) or `boost::variant`:

```cpp
#include <variant>

struct a {
  // declaration omitted
};

struct b {
  // declaration omitted
};

using ab = std::variant<a, b>;

// ptr is determined at runtime
auto obj = (ptr == nullptr) ? ab{a{}} : ab{b{}};
```